# Allowing static method to access DAO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm building a web application using Spring MVC which parses JSON requests into POJOs using @RequestBody/Jackson.

When Jackson creates a POJO, I cannot autowire my DAO service so instead I have created a way to access the DAO statically via a utility method.

```
private static DAOService daoService;

public static User getUserById(int id)
{
  return daoService.getUserDao().getById(id);
}
```

I have spring populate the daoService on application startup which is just a holder for my DAOs.

I do this because my entities that Jackson creates need to retrieve other child entities from the database to complete itself.

This seems to be working but I'm concerned as to whether or not this is safe. Can anyone foresee any issues with this?

I'm assuming it's safe since daoService is never mutated, and the getById method only acts on its own arguments.

Thanks

Edit:

```
    public void setSlot(int id) {
        this.slot = EntityUtils.getSlotById(id);
   }
```

Comment: what about concurrent access to the child entities?

Comment: @efekctive Would they not be separate instances?

Comment: If you are accessing the child entities using the static method no.

Comment: @efekctive The static method returns a new instance of the child, the static method itself doesnt modify it.

Comment: Are these children entities coming from a db? if so one request can modify the data under the nose of a previous one. It does not matter if the if the instance is new if the data is changed

Comment: @efekctive I didnt think the changes would be persisted since the session was already closed and it would be detached. Ill test it out though thanks!

Comment: Ok. Glad to help

Comment: Could you paste a snippet of how you use jackson to create your entities ?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot I've added a snippet... basically I don't want the user to be able to define the object themselves for security - I just want them to provide an ID so I can populate the field myself with an entity I can trust.

Answer (score 0):

You proposal is valid and safe.

If you want to keep your bean clean of the deserialization process you may create a Jackson converter to convert from `Long` to your `Bean`. It requires a bit of plumber but it may worth it:

First annotate your field with a custom converter:

```
public class Foo {
    @JsonDeserialize(converter = SlotConverter.class)
    public void setSlot(Slot slot) {
        this.slot = slot;
    }
}
```

Then define the converter with the `SlotDao` annotated with `@Autowired`. The converter converts from `Long` to `Slot`:

```
public class SlotConverter extends StdConverter<Long, Slot> {
    @Autowired
    private SlotDao slotDao;        

    @Override
    public Slot convert(Long id) {
      return slotDao.getSlotById(id);
    }
}
```

Finally, jackson has to be configured with a custom [Spring instanciator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/SpringHandlerInstantiator.html). Thus `SlotConverter` will be instanciated and configured by Spring:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setConfig(mapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(new SpringHandlerInstantiator(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory())));
```

The following code will deserialize `Foo` using the slot id:

```
Foo foo = mapper.readValue("{\"slot\":10}", Foo.class);
```

Hope it helps!